# If "word" then prints something

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I wanted to create a program for fun to show to one of my friends. Don't be mean, I'm a beginner and have a little problem. The thing is I wanted the program to scan a word and if a word is my friends name "Bob" then it prints "noob", else it prints "pro".

This is what I did, but something seems not to work. It points out that something is wrong with the equal sign ==. Help, guys. This is my coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x;

    printf("Enter the noob's name: ");
    scanf(" %c", &x);

    if (x == "Bob")
        printf("noob\n");
    else
        printf("pro\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare two strings.

Comment: `x` isn't a string. It's a `char`. Please read a beginner's tutorial for C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x[30];

    printf("Enter the noob's name: ");
    scanf(" %s",x);

    if (strcmp(x,"Bob")==0)
        printf("noob\n");
    else
        printf("pro\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in your code:

First, `char x;` declares a variable `x` that can only hold a single character. So, you may want to declare a character array of a larger size.

```
char x[100]; //choose a size
```

Second, string comparison with `==` is not allowed in C. You should do:

```
if(strcmp(x, "Bob") == 0)
```

To use `strcmp` you need to `#include <string.h>`

I will also suggest using `fgets` to read C strings rather than `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x == "Bob")
```

That's not how you compare strings in c. You need to use `strcmp` from the standard library.

[Have a look here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a homework, you might want to try C++ instead.
For example the code below might be a bit less intimidating (or not):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string name;
  cout << "Please enter your name." << endl;
  cin >> name;
  if (name=="bob") {
    cout << "Hello noob" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put [256] after `char x` so you specify how large the string to be.Second the scanf function `scanf(" %c", &x);` change to `scanf("%s,x);`because %s is used to read strings.Then finally put  `if (strcmp(x,"Bob")==0)` instead of `if (x == "Bob")` because that is not the right way to check user input.The same thing happened to me and heres the link [if statement not working ends program immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715541/if-statment-not-working-ends-program-immediately).