# if statement not working ends program immediately

Tags: c, if-statement

Im making a  weather man code but when i ask for the temperature it ends the program. here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    printf("What Is Your Name?\n");
    scanf("%s",&b);
    printf("Hi %s\n", &b);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Im Your Own Weather Man\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Isn't That Great!\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Please Type A Number In\n");
    sleep(1);
    scanf("%d",&a);
    //checking out the number you wrote
    if(a<3)
    {
        printf("Its A Beatiful Day\n");
        printf("%c\n",2);
    }
    if(a>3)
    {
        printf(":(\n");
    }
    if(a==3)
    {
        printf("Its Snowing!\n");
        printf("%c\n",3);
        sleep(5);
        printf("Would you like to know the temprature?\n");
        scanf("%s", &c);
    }
    if(c=='yes')

        printf("20F\n");

    return 0;

}
```

I think its messing up on if(c=='yes')
how would i make it to print out the 20 F?

[EDIT]Thanks for helping me out the new code is right below feel free to use it when you want but give credit to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
int a,b;
char c[5];
char d[30];
printf("What Is Your Name?\n");
scanf("%s",d);
printf("Hi %s\n", d);
sleep(1);
printf("Im Your Own Weather Man\n");
sleep(1);
printf("Isn't That Great!\n");
sleep(1);
printf("Please Type A Number In\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
//checking out the number you wrote
if(a<3)
{
    printf("Its A Beatiful Day\n");
    printf("%c\n",2);
}
if(a>3)
{
    printf("Its A Cloudy Day");
    printf(":(\n");
}
if(a==3)
{
    printf("Its Snowing!\n");
    printf("%c\n",3);
    sleep(5);
    printf("Would you like to know the temprature?\n");
    scanf("%s",c);
}

    if(strcmp("yes", c) == 0)
    printf("20F\n");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Trust me, the `if`s is the least of your worries in this code. I see a plethora of invalid invokes to `scanf()`

Comment: thanks for the info the program now runs smoothly with no warning and errors

Comment: how would i loop all of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in that you're reading a string into an int with this line:

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

Try this instead, where the `%d` is showing that the input is of type int.

```
scanf("%d", &c);
```

Comment: that isn't the only one. there's more.

Comment: Not that it's the cause of the concrete problem in this case, but it should at least be pointed out, also, that `c=='yes'` is not a valid string comparison in C.

Answer (score 3):

`c` is defined as an `int`, but you are treating it like a `char*`.

You should also use `strcmp` instead of `==`.  You can't compare strings with the `==` operator.

Change your definition of `c` to: `char c[128]` or some other arbitrary length.  Then remove the `&` operator when doing scanf: `scanf("%s", c);` Finally, change `if (c=='yes')` to `if (strcmp("yes", c) == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(c=='yes')

        printf("20F\n");
```

You cannot do this because `'yes'` is a falsely declared [character constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwa1sfwk.aspx), and even if it was a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kc54dd5.aspx) like `"yes"` you cannot compare strings directly in c. Use inbuilt library function or write your own function for string comparison/